# How to query all subfolders?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I'm building a windows application that search items from sharepoint document libraries, using the built in sharepoint web services.
I can query all documents from a document library.
**but my problem is How get all folders in all sub folders from a document library?**
i want to get the list of all the folder in a document library, not only in the first level.

below is the query i'm using:

```
<Where>
 <And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /> 
   <Value Type="LookUp">1</Value> 
  </Eq>
 </And>
</Where>
```

this query returns all the folders in a document library but in the first level, i can't get the subfolders.

So i tried to add to the query

```
<QueryOptions>
  <ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' />
</QueryOptions>
```

and the result of this query is null.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Where>
 <And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' LookupId='TRUE' /> 
   <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value> 
  </Eq>
 </And>
</Where>
<QueryOptions>
  <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /> //Subfolders recursively
</QueryOptions>
```

You may test your queries if they are valid or not with [CAML Query builder](http://www.u2u.be/Res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx).

I haven't tested query i pasted....